# Polly Messaging Menu

Tags: messaging-menu, twitter

First, sorry for my bad english.

I "updated" my pc from 11.10 to 12.04 (clean install). After the installation of Polly Twitter Client (0.93.4-0~precise1, the latest from Launchpad), its entries are not showing in the messaging menu as before (in Oneiric).

Its a Polly problem, or there is something wrong with my system?

In any case, there is a solution to this?

Comment: Sounds like something wrong in your system... I'm using Polly in Precise and the Messaging Menu integration is working fine. Does the main "Polly" entry appear, at least?

Comment: Nope, Polly is not showing in the messaging menu. Other problem: Emesene is showing in the tray, like Skype, not in messaging menu.

Comment: Since my Emesene shows in the Messaging Menu, it seems you have indeed some kind of larger issue. I can't guess what it is though, as you have a clean install, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for me either. I have installed a fresh install of 12.04 and Polly is no longer being shown in the message notification menu. I wish I knew why. I even tried uninstalling Gwibber thinking that maybe that was causing the issue but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Polly is probably already installed. I found that adding the correct repository then removing then installing worked for me: To add the correct repo open Terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:conscioususer/polly-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install polly
```

then we remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove polly
```

Then we install it:

```
sudo apt-get install polly
```

And to quote the "How do I install Polly?" also on askubuntu.com

> Then, just select "Polly" to run from the Unity Dash, or run polly
>   from a terminal if you want to catch the messages/output/etc.

Comment: The OP seems to be having a problem with the messaging menu entries not updating and not installing Polly itself..